# Falcon sqlite3 connection

Tags: sqlite, falconframework

I am trying to create my first REST api. I heard that the Falcon is good and easy for beginners. I read the official docs and there is nothing about how to connect to the database.

I have seen the `flask` docs as well and there is well written everything.

```
def get_db():
"""Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
current application context.
"""
if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
    g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
return g.sqlite_db
```

Is there any way to connect SQlite with falcon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any orm to ease the process of database connection and data handling.

A simple SQLite connection using sqlalchemy is :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dbname.db', echo=True)
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
```

This will create a db connection and the same can be used to perform database operations.